# Paralelogramo css

Tags: css, html5, css3

estoy intentando hacer un paralelogramo pero no sé como hacer exactamente el que quiero. He visto algunos que se asemejan bastante al que quiero conseguir.

```css
#paralelogramo {
   width: 150px; 
   height: 100px; 
   background: #bdc3c7;
   -webkit-transform: skew(20deg); 
   -moz-transform: skew(20deg); 
   -o-transform: skew(20deg); 
}
```

```html
<div id="paralelogramo" class="forma"></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Eso es lo maximo que he conseguido.

---

El resultado que quiero conseguir es el siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No quiero que sea una imagen ya que cuando haga el hover y los efectos del mouse no funcionará bien.

Un saludo !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trabaja sobre el eje Y y listo:

```css
#paralelogramo {
   width: 150px; 
   height: 100px; 
   background: #bdc3c7;
   -webkit-transform: skewY(-20deg); 
   -moz-transform: skewY(-20deg); 
   -o-transform: skewY(-20deg); 
   margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="paralelogramo" class="forma"></div>
```

Comment: Creo que es interesante añadir que skew trabaja sobre los dos ejes, el primer parámetro es el eje X y el segundo el eje Y, con lo que `skewY(-20deg)` es equivalente a `skew(0 -20deg)`

Comment: Gracias Pablo Lozano , eso me acalra las cosas